# How to keep object member variables private to a thread in a multi threaded environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I have a multi threaded program that opens a few threads to query an external CRM and save the results in an in-memory IDictionary in order to speed up the system.

I'm a little confused about multi threading and critical sections. I want my class `QueryThreadProcess` to have a thread which runs the query and to manage starting and stopping the query. It has an object of type query and saves the results in a list.

The class `QueryManager` will kill all the processes or start all processes, basically collection wide methods.

I have a feeling that the private members for `QueryThreadProcess` are shared between all threads. How would I be able to make them private to each thread, but also kill each thread separately from an external class?

**I don't want to lock because I want all the threads to run parallel.**

Here is my manager class:

```
public class QueryManager
{
    private IDictionary<int, QueryThreadProcess> _queries;

    public QueryManager()
    {
        _queries = new Dictionary<int, QueryThreadProcess>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CreateQueryThreadsFromDb();
        StartAllThreads();
    }

    private void StartAllThreads()
    {
        if (_queries != null && _queries.Count > 0)
        {
            StopThreadsAndWaitForKill();

        }

        foreach (var query in _queries)
            query.Value.Start();
    }

    private void CreateQueryThreadsFromDb()
    {
        var queries = new QueryProvider().GetAllQueries();
        if (_queries != null && _queries.Count > 0)
        {
            StopThreadsAndWaitForKill();
            _queries.Clear();
        }

        foreach (var query in queries)
            _queries.Add(query.Id, new QueryThreadProcess(query));

    }

    private void StopThreadsAndWaitForKill()
    {
        KillAllThreads();
        while (!AreAllThreadsKilled()) { }
    }

    private void KillAllThreads()
    {
        foreach (var query in _queries)
            query.Value.Kill();
    }

    private bool AreAllThreadsKilled()
    {
        return _queries.All(query => query.Value.IsKilled);
    }

    public IList<User> GetQueryResultById(int id)
    {
        return _queries[id].Result;
    }
}
```

and here is my class for QueryProcesses which holds the threads that do the actual query:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using Intra.BLL.MessageProviders;
using Intra.BO;
using Intra.BO.Messages;


namespace Intra.BLL.QueryProcess
{
    internal class QueryThreadProcess
    {
        private readonly Thread _thread;
        private readonly Query _query;
        private bool _isStoppingQuery = false;
        private bool _isKilled = true;

        private IList<User> _result;
        private readonly object _objSync = new object();

        public QueryThreadProcess(Query query)
        {
            _query = query;
            _thread = new Thread(RetrieveQueries);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _isStoppingQuery = true;
            while (!_isKilled) { }
            _isStoppingQuery = false;
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void RetrieveQueries()
        {
             const string BROKERNAME = "bla";

            _isKilled = false;
            while (!_isStoppingQuery)
            {
                Broker broker = new BrokerProvider().GetBrokerByName(BROKERNAME);
                var users = new QueryProvider().GetUserObjectsByQuery(_query, ParaTokenGenerator.GetBrokerAuthToken(broker));
                _result = users;
            }
            _isKilled = true;
        }

        public bool IsKilled
        {
            get { return _isKilled; }
        }


        public IList<User> Result
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_objSync)
                    return _result;
            }
        }

        public void Kill()
        {
            _isStoppingQuery = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating an instance of QueryThreadProcess for each query, thus no sharing of private members can occur as each instance is completely separate.

Comment: The private members of QueryThreadProcess are indeed private to each instance.  That said, the _queries dictionary in the QueryManager is not thread-safe, so I would recommend locking on any access to the dictionary.  In addition, there may be other race condition subtleties if you expect some of those methods to be called concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really answer your question, but it looks like a more modern approach using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) of .NET 4 could save you some headache. Controlling Threads by yourself isn't necessary. It looks like you could refactor your classes to a few lines of code and get rid of the described problems.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4 has [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) which may be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

The _thread and _query fields probably don’t matter as they are declared readonly and are not changed after each thread is run. These are not shared between worker threads as they are private to the class and you create a separate instance of the class for each thread.

_isStoppingQuery and _isKilled are accessed by both the worker thread and the controlling thread. As such these should be declared volatile to ensure they are not cashed in a processor register and don’t suffer from execution reordering.

There is a potential issue with _result. The lock in Result/get is not enough to protect the contents of _result. It is only protecting the reference to the list not the list itself. However as your worker thread is only overwriting the reference each cycle it may not be an issue. I would probably do away with the lock on _objSync and declare _result volatile too.

Comment: On a side note, the guarantees enforced by volatile are weaker than those enforced by a MemoryBarrier (including those implicitly created when using a lock.)  It's very easy to get the subtleties wrong here, so I would recommend against ever using volatile (or even an explicit MemoryBarrier, for that matter) unless you're a threading expert specifically designing lockless data structures and algorithms.